# Whats wrong with this C program? (Scanning from terminal using scanf)

Tags: c, scanf

The program just builds but the prompt just hangs like its stuck in an infinite loop.

The first printf statement is not even run.

The idea of the program is to take an MMSI, name, position, course and speed and put them in a struct for writing to a file.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ship *current_ship;

    current_ship = getShipInfo();
    //writeShip(current_ship);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
ship * getShipInfo() {
    ship *current_ship;
    current_ship = malloc(sizeof(ship));
    int MMSI, course;
    char name[51];
    float lat, lon, speed;

    printf("Enter MMSI (9 digits):\n"); 
    scanf(" %9d", &MMSI);

    printf("Enter ship name (upto 50 characters):\n");
    scanf(" %51s", name);

    printf("Enter ship latitude (real number with upto 3 decimal places):\n");
    scanf(" %f", &lat);

    printf("Enter ship longitude (real number with upto 3 decimal places):\n");
    scanf(" %f", &lon);

    printf("Enter course made good (degrees from true north):\n");
    scanf(" %3d", &course);

    printf("Enter speed over the ground (in knots with exactly one decimal place):\n");
    scanf(" %f", &speed);

    current_ship->MMSI = MMSI;
    strcpy(current_ship->name, name);
    current_ship->lat = lat;
    current_ship->lon = lon;
    current_ship->course = course;
    current_ship->speed = speed;

    return current_ship;
}
```

Comment: Is the terminal in any special mode that's preventing `stdout` from being flushed?  Try inserting `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` call.

Comment: What have you tried by way of debugging? For instance, if you `return NULL;` as the very first statement in `getShipInfo()`, does the program run its course? Things like that.

Comment: Better to post full code with ship structure declaration and the function declaration etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you allocated ship->name?

`current_ship->name = malloc(51);`

Answer (score 0):

Is `ship * getShipInfo()` declared before the main() function?
This could be a problem.

Comment: Its declared in a header file, thats not the problem

Comment: Hm, so this is not a complete program?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are spaces at the start of scanf format strings. Your larger problem is using scanf at all. Just use fgets instead.